# How to stop Java from rounding float

Tags: java

I am trying to divide a number in a float:

`float num = 9/5`

but this gives me 1.0 when it should give me 1.8.

I've tried using a double in case it is a problem with the precision but it still gives me the same error. Is there anyway for me to get the write answer?

Comment: `float num = 9.0f / 5.0f;` or `float num = ((float) 9) / 5;`

Comment: or `float num = 9f / 5;` many ways to skin this cat

Comment: float num =(float) 9/5